# Uploading Image PHP file type?

Tags: php, image

I am trying to upload an image but the whole code seems messed up, I send a .jpg it's says "invalide image type" and when I send a .JAR it successfully sends it why? 
here is my code I am trying to upload 3MB images max with only .jpg and .png images files.

```
<?php 
            if(isset($_POST["changepic"])) {
                    $new_file_name = "profileN.jpg";

                    //if no errors...
                    if(!$_FILES["photo"]["error"]) {

                      if((!$_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || (!$_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/png" )) {
                        echo $alert->danger("The image file is invalide.");

                        //Max size 3MB
                      } elseif($_FILES["photo"]["size"] > (3000000)) { 
                            echo $alert->danger("The image size is to large, 3MB maximum.");
                      } else {
                            //Move it to user's Folder.
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "../assets/images/u/{$user->username}/{$new_file_name}");
                            $file->compressImg("../assets/images/u/{$user->username}/profileN.jpg", "../assets/images/u/{$user->username}/profile.jpg", 75);
                            echo $alert->success("Your profile picture has been changed !");
                        }
                } else {
                    echo $alert->danger("There was an error uploading the image, please try again.");
                }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: because it was true on the condition `!$_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/png"`

Comment: @roullie But I send an error after that, I do not want to send an error if the file is valid ^_^?

Comment: you should use && operator to check the file types. See my answer below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method

```
$valid_formats = array("jpeg","png");
$name = $_FILES['EXCEL_FILE']['name'];
list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
{
    // Code if format is right
}
else
{
    echo 'Invalid format';
}
```

Comment: this is not the strict check  because one can rename the file extension. for strict check you need to check the mime type...

Answer (score 0):

you should use `&&` operators since you only wanted jpg and png file type.

```
if((!$_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") && (!$_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/png" )) {
```

Comment: It works when I upload Images, but It still says Successful upload, when I send a .jar

Comment: that's weird.  can you see what is the mime type of that jar file?

Comment: I do not know, but I does the same with .zip, .tar, .html etc I only got an error when the .zip was to large.. I can't seem to understand why it says it upload the .JARs. I must have malformed the shape of the "if" statements they must not add up well.. @roullie

Comment: This is not the strict mime type... use  $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);